# I need change return in laravel. object to array {} to [] (Error trying to diff '[object Object])

Tags: php, laravel

I need change return object to array in laravel api.
anyone guide? I am getting error, cant figure out why??

change **{}** to this **[]**

> ERROR Error: "Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and
>   iterables are allowed (API Laravel and front-end angular 7)

my **code** api Laravel

```
public function show($id)
    {

        $arCategoria = \App\Favorito::join('categoria', 'categoria.cd_categoria', '=', 'link.cd_categoria')
        ->select('*')
        ->where('categoria.cd_categoria_pai',$id)
        ->where('link.cd_usuario',$this->token['cd_usuario'])
        ->where('link.bo_ativo',true)
            ->get();
        return (array)$this->processarCategoria($arCategoria);
    }
    public function processarCategoria($arCategoria){
        $ar = array();
        $cont = 0;
        foreach($arCategoria as $key => $value){
            $ar[$value['no_categoria'].'_'.$value['cd_categoria']][] =  (array)array(
                'no_link'=>$value['no_link'],
                'cd_link'=>$value['cd_link'],
                'vl_link'=>$value['vl_link'],
                'bo_ativo'=>$value['bo_ativo'],
                'link'=>$value['link']
            );
           $cont++;
        }

        return (array)$ar;
    }
```

my return of laravel api

```
{
    "Documentation_3": [
        {
            "no_link": "stackoverflow",
            "cd_link": 5,
            "vl_link": null,
            "bo_ativo": 1,
            "link": "https://stackoverflow.com"
        },
        {
            "no_link": "Adventures of Time",
            "link": "http://adventuresoftime.com.br"
        }
    ],
    "Things to buy_5": [
        {
            "no_link": "Games",
            "link": "Games.com.br"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Every element in "Documentation_3" and "Things to buy_5" is an object.

Comment: What about change `return (array)$this->processarCategoria($arCategoria);` to `return $this->processarCategoria($arCategoria->toArray());`

Comment: Eloquent supports JSON serialization out of the box: [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json)

Comment: I modify to `$arCategoria->toArray()` just a second ago, how about that?

Comment: @Autodesk same return  :(

Comment: Could you `dd($arCategoria->toArray())` before to `return` and see if it is an array?

Comment: The simple way is to convert it to json and reconvert a json to array by using json_decode(json_encode($ar), true)

Comment: Change this return (array)$this->processarCategoria($arCategoria); to  return [$this->processarCategoria($arCategoria->toArray ())]; and check

Comment: @Autodesk with dd https://i.imgur.com/GJerJ3R.png with return https://i.imgur.com/XLqonn2.png

Comment: The second png file looks like someone json_encode it.

Comment: It turns out, laravel did it. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#creating-responses

Answer (score 0):

If `dd($this->processarCategoria($arCategoria->toArray()))` is a plain PHP array, which means it works.

Btw, I think your original code works,too, maybe you `dd((array) $this->processarCategoria($arCategoria))` and check.

---

According to [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting), (array)$scalarValue is exactly the same as array($scalarValue)

According to [Laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-toarray), The toArray() method converts the collection into a plain PHP array.

---

And the reason why the array become a `JSON` after `return`, as if someone using the `json_encode` PHP function, is because:

> Laravel automatically convert the array into a JSON response, in
>   addition to returning strings from your routes and controllers.
>   [Laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#creating-responses)

I.e., laravel convert array to JSON, so it may show on the screen.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    //return is the same as dd()
    //dd(json_encode([1=>'a', 2=>'b', 3=>'c']));
    return [1=>'a', 2=>'b', 3=>'c'];
});
```